# Traceroute Results

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, traceroute

I’ve been looking at Traceroute code from [a blog post](https://blog.appbeat.io/post/c-sharp-method-for-very-fast-and-efficient-traceroute-network-diagnostic-tool).

The problem is that when I try to get the results to C# Form. The only thing I get is the completed IP on one row; hop, ms and IP. I was trying to get a list or be able to add (string (Tracing route to 172.217.7.174 over a maximum of 30 hops:) hop, ms and IP Address) to a ListView.

```cs
private async void btnAwait_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var Results = await asyncTraceRoute.TryTraceRouteInternalAsync("google.com", 30);
    txtTraceroute.Text = Results.Message;
}
```

Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? We've got no code to start from. My guess is that this is something to do with the fact you have 15 parallel tasks and the way you are handing the results to the UI thread...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Heretic. All of the code is from the link that I posted. I added it to a class and the code current is how I thought I should be able to retrieve the data from the class.

Comment: You are invoking the wrong (internal) method. Please check the answer (tested & working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the method (`TryTraceRouteInternalAsync`) actually gives a hint that something is being done in an incorrect manner.

This method invokes only one ping and that's why you get just one result.

The actual method you need to invoke is `TryTraceRouteAsync` but I have a strong feeling that you had chosen the other one because it returns an accessible object, with a string Message property.

If you do the following, the `TryTraceRouteAsync` method will asynchronously invoke `TryTraceRouteInternalAsync` (MAX_HOPS = 15) times simultaneously and write all the results into the streamWriter.

You can just call this method and get all the results you are looking for:

```
    private async Task<string> TraceRt()
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        await TraceRoute.TryTraceRouteAsync("google.com.tr", streamWriter);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader stringReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        return stringReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Oguz Ozgul. That's exactly what I was looking for. I do have an add-on question about that Class. Is there a way to also add DNS lookup using the asynchronous to associate DNS with the IP's?

Comment: You're welcome. We query the DNS records using Dns.GetHostEntry method, and it also has an Async implementation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentryasync?view=netframework-4.8